# How to join DataTable

Tags: c#, join, datatable, sum

T1 and T2 are DataTables with following fields

```
T1(SPEC, DWGNO, ITEM NAME, DESCRIPTION, SIZE, AMOUNT)

T2(SPEC, DWGNO, ITEM NAME, DESCRIPTION, SIZE, AMOUNT)
```

If SPEC, DWGNO, ITEM NAME, ESCRIPTION, SIZE are equal

```
    AMOUNT = T1AMOUNT -  T2AMOUNT;
    New Column 1st(T1 AMOUNT), 2nd(T2 AMOUNT)

and T1 Amount add to 1st, T2 Amount add to 2nd
```

IF SPEC, DWGNO, ITEM NAME, ESCRIPTION, SZIE is different Then  T1 Amount is add to 1st column and T2 Amount is add to 2st column

I need the join table

```
TJ (SPEC, DWGNO, ITEM NAME, DESCRIPTION, SIZE, 1st-2nd, 1st, 2nd)
```

How this can be done in C# code in a simple way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you...

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Table1");
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Table2");
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable("Table3");

        if (dt1.Rows[0]["A1"] == dt2.Rows[0]["A2"])
        {
            dt3.Rows.Add(dt1.Rows[0]["A1"].ToString(), dt1.Rows[0]["B1"].ToString(), dt1.Rows[0]["C1"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dt1.Rows[0]["D1"]) + Convert.ToInt32(dt1.Rows[0]["D2"]));
        }
```

You can use loops for all the rows of the tables, and basic maths to calculate the columns.